# Pandas .loc returns key error for some labels

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm making a function that returns 'id' for an input of product name.

```
                   id
pName   
ZYMOFLAM D TAB 10s  1
ZYROP INJ 10000IU   2
ZYROP INJ 4000IU    3
ZYTANIX TAB 5MG 10s 4
ZYTEE RB GEL 10ML   5
```

```
df.loc['ZYTANIX TAB 5MG 10s']
```

returns

```
id    4
Name: ZYTANIX TAB 5MG 10s, dtype: int64
```

but `df.loc['ZYTEE RB GEL 10ML']`
returns KeyError

Why does this happen?

Comment: Check `print (df.index.tolist())`, maybe `traling whitespace`, then need `df.index = df.index.str.strip()`

Comment: (['ZYMOFLAM D TAB  10s',
 'ZYROP INJ  10000IU',
 'ZYROP INJ  4000IU',
 'ZYTANIX TAB 5MG 10s',
 'ZYTEE RB GEL  10ML'])  no trailing whitespace.

Comment: then no idea. It should working nice.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for trying to help. Is there a possibility of unrecognisable white spaces between words in the item name?

Comment: if use df.index = df.index.str.strip() it help?

Comment: Tried that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first do the cleaning part and recreate your dataframe before applying any slicing method. To remove and trailing whitespace or extra spaces in between words you can do:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['pName'] = df.pName.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.strip().split(' ')))
df = df.set_index('pName')
```

now try

```
df.loc['ZYTEE RB GEL 10ML']
```

Comment: This apply function makes all the labels into NAN

Comment: Right now I'm working around by replacing all the spaces in between. (df['pName'] = df['pName'].str.replace(" ","")). This doesn't throw the key error. But I still need to arrive at the right solution with spaces.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake. I have updated the code. Hope it will work now.